# how to sort string type array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I want to sort array object based on specific `string` type value in `Typescript`. Below code I have tried but not working

```
this.deviceapp = data.Devices[0].Products.sort((product)=>product.Status="Non-Compliant")
```

I need "Non-Compliant" records at top, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean `==` instead of `=` in `product.Status="Non-Compliant"`

Comment: @Mamun - Why vote for close?

Comment: @Mamun Take a look at the note at the bottom: (Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya, does it guarantee all the close voters are the down voters?

Comment: @Mamun - Not at all. I am not blaming you :)

Comment: My mistake, misread the comments as *down* vote, retract the *close* vote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `product.Status="Non-Compliant"` you are just assigning the value "Non-Compliant" to `product.status`.

The `.sort` function expects -1, 0 or -1 as a return value. Try this :

```js
let products = [
   { Status : "Compliant"},
   { Status : "Non-Compliant"},
   { Status : "Compliant"},
   { Status : "Compliant"},
   { Status : "Non-Compliant"},
   { Status : "Compliant"},
]

products.sort( product => product.Status==="Non-Compliant" ? -1 : 1)

console.log(products)
```

Comment: Someone downvoted because s/he thinks that the question is related to a typo problem, however, the question it's far away from a typo problem.

Comment: dv, not me, but for same `Status` values, there should be zero as return value. without, the sorting takes longer.

Comment: @NinaScholz - For that do I need to make Status field bool?

Comment: no, just a different cb, like `(a, b) => (b.Status === 'Non-Compliant') - (a.Status === 'Non-Compliant')`.

Comment: @NinaScholz - It shows an error `left side operand must be any number or bigint`.  Status is type string.

Comment: add a number conversion ... `(a, b) => Number(b.Status === 'Non-Compliant') - Number(a.Status === 'Non-Compliant')`